# How do the JavaScript function toUpperCase vs CSS transform-text:uppercase compare with respect to performance?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

Is there any performance difference between using Javascript function `toUpperCase` vs using CSS `text-transform: uppercase`?

To clarify, let's take the simplest case:

```
<h1 id="greetings"></h1>

<script>
   var name = "Nour"
   document.getElementById("greetings").innerHTML="Hello" + name.toUpperCase();
</script>
```

rather than:

```
<script>
   var name = "Nour"
   document.getElementById("greetings").innerHTML="Hello" + name;
</script>
<style>
#greetings {
 text-transform:uppercase
}
</style>
```

What's the performance difference between the two?

Comment: Performance is based on a bunch of criteria. Since we do not know what that is in your case, not sure what we can say.

Comment: @epascarello take the simplest case, where we just retrieve the text from anywhere and want to show it on an HTML page.

Comment: You can measure this effect with the DevTools.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 3):

The obvious difference is that when you're using `toUpperCase()`, it is a one-time operation, meaning that if you modify the text again, it won't be uppercased. However, if you add the `text-transform: uppercase;` CSS rule, the element will remain uppercased even if you change the text. See the two snippets:

#### JavaScript's `toUpperCase`:

```js
function upper() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerText = document.getElementById("text").innerText.toUpperCase();
}

function change() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerText = "This text will be sentence case";
}
```

```html
<p id="text">This is some text.</p>
<button onclick="upper()">Click me to make upper case</button>
<button onclick="change()">Click me to change the text</button>
```

#### CSS's `text-transform: uppercase;`:

```js
function upper() {
  document.getElementById("text").style.textTransform = "uppercase";
}

function change() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerText = "This text will be upper case";
}
```

```html
<p id="text">This is some text.</p>
<button onclick="upper()">Click me to make upper case</button>
<button onclick="change()">Click me to change the text</button>
```

You'll see in the first snippet, the text did not remain uppercase when changed, however in the second one, the new text was uppercased without you doing anything, as the rule was already in place. This is the largest difference between the two - `toUpperCase()` is one-time, `text-transform: uppercase;` lasts until you remove it. Hopefully this helps you!

## Edit:

To get the different speeds of these two methods, I have added console.log statements before and after both methods below. As Stack Overflow shows split-second console messages, you can use these to determine for yourself the differing speeds:

#### JavaScript's `toUpperCase`:

```js
function upper() {
    console.log("Before JS");
  document.getElementById("text").innerText = document.getElementById("text").innerText.toUpperCase();
    console.log("After JS");
}

function change() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerText = "This text will be sentence case";
}
```

```html
<p id="text">This is some text.</p>
<button onclick="upper()">Click me to make upper case</button>
<button onclick="change()">Click me to change the text</button>
```

#### CSS's `text-transform: uppercase;`:

```js
function upper() {
  
    console.log("Before CSS");
document.getElementById("text").style.textTransform = "uppercase";
    console.log("After CSS");
}

function change() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerText = "This text will be upper case";
}
```

```html
<p id="text">This is some text.</p>
<button onclick="upper()">Click me to make upper case</button>
<button onclick="change()">Click me to change the text</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of which has better "performance". It answers a different question, "what is the difference between them".

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. However, I was asking about the difference in performance.
Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the title, not just the body.

Comment: So you mean the difference in speed?

Comment: @Jack Bashford yes

Answer (score 0):

Logically rendering the style rule and applying a transform to the text will certainly  take few more ticks however the difference of the page load speed I don't think, it will be noticeable.

Comment: Why would rendering the style rule take more ticks? Do you have a reference for that assumption? There are many places where doing something with CSS is much faster than the corresponding JavaScript/DOM methods (e.g., animation).

Answer (score 0):

There is not much different in performance between them. However, if the target value is nullable it's better to use "**transform : uppercase**" to avoid need of extra checking (both code and time) to stay away from errors like **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toUpperCase')**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).